# why $G(z)=\frac{f(z)}z, z\ne 0; f'(0), z=0$ is holomorphic?

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm reading Gong Sheng's [Concise Complex Analysis](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/9812706933) to get some basic understanding.

On $\S 2.5$ page 66 Theorem 2.19 (Schwarz Theorem) it says

> If a holomorphic function $f(z)$ maps the unit disc $D = D(O, 1)$ to itself and $f(0) = 0$
>
> ... Let $G(z)=\frac{f(z)}{z}$ for $z\ne 0$, and $G(z)=f'(0)$ for $z=0$
>
> Then $G(z)$ is holomorphic on $D$.

I wonder why?

So far from that book I only know such ways to determine a function is holomorphic

1. By definition, that is $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $U$, iff $\forall z\in U$, $\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(z+h)-f(z)}{h}$ exists, here $h \in \mathscr C$.
2. Cauchy-Riemann equation, that is, if $f(z) \in \mathscr L ^1 (U)$ and fulfills the Cauchy-Riemann equation $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x} = -i \frac{\partial f}{\partial y}$, then $f$ is holomorphic on $U$, here $z=x+iy$.
3. Power series expansion (Taylor series): $f(z)$ is holomorphic in $U$ iff f has a power series expansion $\forall z \in U$.
4. Morera theorem:  If $f(z)$ is continuous on $U$ and 
   the integral of $f$ along any rectifiable closed curve is zero, then $f(z)$ is 
   holomorphic on $U$.

It seems none of such 1-4 could get to the conclusion that $G(z)$ is a holomorphic function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use number $3$ - the series expansion criterion. If $f(0)=0,$ it means that there is no free coefficient in the series, thus one can divide by $z$.